# Best practice referencing projects

Tags: .net, web-services, dll

In a large website with lots of projects (meaning DLLs) that use each other - what's the best way to go through?

A. Put everything in one bin/output folder. Directly reference DLLs to eachother. Will this make the projects heavily overloaded?

B. Regardless of where I put DLLs, make them into webservices and have them access eachother that way.

C. Other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple projects interacting with each other, then its better to have them in one solution and then reference the project in your executable project. But if you can't put them in one solution and you want to use dlls only, then its better to put them inside a folder in project and reference them from there. This way you will be able to manage the dlls in one set. I am not sure if that will make your project heavily overloaded. If you need all of these dlls, then it doesn't matter where you put them, eventually they will all get copied to bin/debug folder. 
But if you want to expose functioning through services for each project and then consume it in your executable project, this may cause some performance issues. You need to take [Design Consideration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658090.aspx) in account